# ARR Redirecting Rule (ERROR 404)

Tags: iis, tomcat, arr

Well I'm using ARR to make IIS act as a front-end to Tomcat where my application is. 
The rule I'm using is working only for the first index page and that would be it.

Rule is

```
Patter (Wildcards) *myapp*

Rewrite To: http://myserver:8080/myapp/

I only have one box checked (Stop Processing).
```

When I'm calling myapp using IIS (myserver/myapp) it is redirecting me successfully into the myapp index page, after that it is giving me an **ERROR 404**

```
Requested URL      http://myserver:80/login
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login
```

Why wouldn't IIS point where my application is? Why is it referring back to IIS main folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, as assumed it was from the rule. 
It should be like this:

```
Patter (Wildcards) *myapp*

Rewrite To: http://myserver:8080/myapp{R:2}
```

Which means "append the second asterisk to the url (anything that comes after myapp)"